# Inserting text in Email body using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the following VBA macro to mail a range of cells from Excel

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Q133").Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "demo"
      .Item.To = "abc@abc.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Testing mail"
      .Item.Send
   End With
```

I want to modify the code to insert some text in the end.
I tried using

```
.Item.HTMLBody = "Random text"
```

but the mail doesnt contain the text.

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong and what is the correct way to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you can do that. perhaps `1` Copy the range "A2:Q133" to a new worksheet `2` Insert custom text in say "A144" and then use "A2:Q144" as the range? OR see [THIS](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) method by Ron De Bruin

Answer (score 1):

With `MailEnvelope` you send the whole sheet as body of your email.

Introduction allows you to add some text before a [mail item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863622.aspx), but you have no other way to add something at the end than append something to the Excel sheet.

Even if you modify the `Body` or the `HTMLBody`, this doesn't have effect on the email.

Maybe you could try to add same the message as draft and reopen it as a different object to modify it, but it seems over complicated. Much easier just to add some temporary text at the end of the excel spreasheet and remove it after `.Item.Send`